# How to use Open With Dialog box when file format not recognized

Tags: c#, winforms

Friends.,

I Creating an excel Sheet Through my code, then opening that created Excel through MS office, 
If MS Office Not Installed in that Particular PC means "open with" Dialog Box Have to appear to open that Created Excel Sheet..

What can I do..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Process.Start("FullFileNamePath");
```

if windows cant open file, it shows message to select a program from a list of installed programs.

Answer (score 1):

Please use System.Diagnostics in using or

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("FullFileNamePath");
```

Information will be helpful for beginners like me.

Answer (score 1):

Please use System.Diagnostics in using or

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("FullFileNamePath");
```